# How to receive email for domain registered with Amazon Route53

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, amazon-route53

I registered a domain iqxxxx.io on Route53 which will be hosting web service. A hosted zone is generated automatically after the registration is complete. I created a record set which points to an Elastic Beanstalk environment.

In order to enable HTTPS, I tried to request a SSL certificate via AWS Certificate Manager for domain `*.iqxxxx.io`. I chose "email validation" which means an email will be sent to the domain owner with following emails:

```
administrator@iqxxxx.io
admin@iqxxxx.io
hostmaster@iqxxxx.io
webmaster@iqxxxx.io
postmaster@iqxxxx.io
```

When I registered the domain, my own email address is listed for all "Registrant contact", "Administrative contact", "Technical contact", although only "Registrant contact" is shown as `verified`.

How am I supposed to get all the verification email that was sent to these `iqxxxx.io` emails? Is that because `Administrative contact` and `Technical contact` have not been verified yet? What do I need to do to get these verified?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can now configure ACM to validate the cert via DNS, which sounds like it would be a much easier solution.

But if you want to do it via email, you will need to create an MX record for your domain, and point it to the appropriate SES endpoint for incoming email.

Then set up a default rule set, and point it to an SNS topic.  You can then set up your actual email, confirm your subscription, and then when you try to use email validation for the domain you should receive the 5 emails that get sent (admin@, hostmaster@, etc)

The email body will be in JSON, but you can pull out the confirmation link easily enough.

Comment: I followed [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/gs-acm-validate-dns.html) to do DNS validation. After adding the CNAME record `_3639ac514e785e898d2646601fa951d5.iqxxxx.io` from the ACM console, it appears in Record Set of Route53. Although it seems the validation will take hours to go through, I guess my part is done. The record I want to apply the certificate on is actually an `Alias` type of subdomain `nexus.iqxxxx.io`. It seems the certificate is only associated with the CNAME record. Will this cover all other records as long as they are in the same domain?

Comment: Once DNS has been updated, especially if you are using Route53, it generally takes less than 30 minutes.  Certificates are for hostnames and don't care at all how the DNS is set up.  ACM supports wildcards as well.

Comment: Bingo! The status changed from `Pending` to `Issued`. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Answer

You must have an email from one of these emails,

administrator@iqxxxx.io
admin@iqxxxx.io
hostmaster@iqxxxx.io
webmaster@iqxxxx.io
postmaster@iqxxxx.io

AWS will send most of admin@iqxxxx.ie.