# AWS Certificate Manager - validate domain by email - where do the emails go?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53, aws-certificate-manager

I've used the "validate by email" option for getting an ACM certificate for my website (We can call it example.com).

In the details section of the validation status, I see that an email was sent to:

```
webmaster@example.com
postmaster@example.com
hostmaster@example.com
admin@example.com
administrator@example.com
```

The problem is that I have no idea where this emails are going, or how to check them. I never remember setting up any sort of email associated with my domain but I do have my domain on a hosted zone using Route53.

Amazon's documentation fails to provide any help on this. I am wanting to actually access the emails that were sent from ACM (are they in S3? Route53? Do I need command-line?).

Comment: The email verification method assumes you have already done your own email setup for the domain. If you don't already have working email for the domain, I recommend using the DNS verification method. If you can't do that, configure mail to be delivered to amazon SES -> S3.

Comment: ugh.. ok. Well the problem with DNS verifcation is this: on go-daddy, I've re-configured the domain to have amazon name-servers associated w/ route 53. So I get this message on GoDaddy: We can't display your DNS information because your nameservers aren't managed by us.

Comment: I'm unclear on how to proceed if I go the DNS verification route. I'm assuming I would need to add the CNS name on GoDaddy, which it seems I currently cannot do. Thanks in advance for your reply.

Comment: If you configured your nameservers in godaddy to use route53, then route53 is where you need to add the CNAME. If the hosted zone is in the same account as the cert you are trying to provision, there should be a button to create the records automatically.

Comment: Hmm, so I don't actually need to re-configure a CNAME in GoDaddy?  I thought I did, but it sounds like Route53 takes care of that when I hit "add records" (i added the dns records by following the prompts in ACM).

Comment: That should be all you need if you configured the nameserver records correctly in godaddy.

Comment: If for some reason you really want to get the emails that are sent out, you can go down the route as mentioned and uses SES to get your mails. Check the answer from chris on this topic [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48287303/how-to-receive-email-for-domain-registered-with-amazon-route53?rq=1) You basically set up ses with a rule set to forward to an sns topic which you can either subscribe to your real email or push to an sqs queue and see the mails.